# Console log area has extra rows

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to console log a variable I got from PHP through AJAX. I don't know why the console log area for my PHP variable (F01) is bigger than my HTML variable (F06).

[this is image of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgRL4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has newlines in it. check the network then response in dev tools. Also you need to call `exit();` or `die();` after `echo` in your php file just in case it has html elements or newlines/spaces after your closing php tag